# Optimize objectives function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a questions on the MATLAB function gamultiobj function in obtaining Pareto front.

How to convert the minimization of multiple functions using genetic algorithm in a maxmization problem with linear constraints?

For example, instead of solving:

```
Min [2*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1));
     x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(-x(2))];

%with  Bounds
lb = [0;0];
ub = [1;1];
```

Find the following max:

```
Max [2*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1));
            -x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(-x(2))];

%with  Bounds
lb = [0;0];
ub = [1;1];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for `max(f(x))` is the same as `-min(-f(x))`

[image: Maximize and minimize]

Very simple, since [`gamultiobj`](https://mathworks.com/help/gads/gamultiobj.html) only minimizes, you can make Matlab maximize your problem by changing the sign of every coefficient of your objective function like this:

```
f = -[2*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1));
     x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(-x(2))];
```

You don't need to change your lower and upper bounds.

Then, once you run the function and obtain the solutions, make sure to invert their sign too. This is essential, otherwise your solutions will be wrong.

This kind of behavior can also be found in the functions [`linprog`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html) and [`intlinprog`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html) which are used to solve linear programming problems.

Comment: Thank you for this usefull trick. Does this kind of behiavour also appears with the MATLAB function fminimax ?

Comment: That's correct. The `fminimax` also minimizes, so you need apply this same method.